# Sudz-C for iOS - Doesn't work over 3G/edge connections but works over wifi

Tags: ios

So I am using iOS 5.0.1 with iPhone 4s (tested with 4 too) and using Sudz-c generated code to connect our web service. The service works great over wifi but if I try over 3g or EDGE connection it doesn't work. I got following error:
It loads the url from the Safari, even over 3g/edge.

```
2012-01-15 18:32:13.987 SudzCExamples[487:707] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x18af60 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://sensored/app/soap/sensored/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://sensored/app/soap/sensored/, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x18afa0 "The request timed out."}
2012-01-15 18:32:13.988 SudzCExamples[487:707] Error: The request timed out.
```

The url request in SoapRequest ever gets respone

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`

Any advices?

**UPDATE:** If I use other server using the same code, it works great over 3g too. It seems that the problem is in our server side code. Any ideas what could cause this?

**UPDATE 2:** 
Phone 1: The app works only over wifi.(Carrier: Sonera)
Phone 2: The app works only over wifi.(Carrier: Sonera)
Phone 3: The app works only over wifi.(Carrier: Sonera)
Phone 4: The app works great over 3g and wifi. (Carrier: Elisa)
iPad: The app works great over 3g and wifi. (Carrier: Elisa)

If I use our service with phone 4, it works great over 3g too. If I tether internet connection from phone 4 to iPhone1 (or 2 or 3), it will work over that tethered wifi, but not over its own 3g. If I tether phone 1 (or 2 or 3) connection to the phone 4, it doesn't work over that tethered wifi on phone 4.

Only difference which I can notice between those phones are that Phone 1 and 2 and 3 uses Finnish internet connection provider called TeliaSonera and the phone 4 uses Elisa.

**UPDATE 3:** I run the app in iphone simulator and it works great. After I start Charles Proxy it doesn't work anymore. The request goes successfully to the server and actually it gives the response too, even the app fails.
There is the request and the response which the Charles Proxy software shows:

Request

```
POST /app/soap/sensored/ HTTP/1.1
Host: sensored
User-Agent: Sensored/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.3 Darwin/11.2.0
Content-Length: 396
Accept: */*
SOAPAction: urn:sensoredSoapModelAction
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: PHPSESSID=a60ef32d72121d625a95b75b90d48a22
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:sensored"><soap:Body><checkUpdates><authHash>daswwe12e2e2wweqwessd</authHash><lastCheckDate>2012-01-19 05:45</lastCheckDate></checkUpdates></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2012 05:45:34 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 537
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:sensored" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:checkUpdatesResponse><checkUpdatesReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">[dds2d,asddd2,a0333f,20dks]</checkUpdatesReturn></ns1:checkUpdatesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Overview

```
URL http://sensored/app/soap/sensored/
Status Complete
Response code 200 OK
Protocol HTTP/1.1
Method POST
Content-type text/xml; charset=utf-8
Client address /127.0.0.1
Remote Address sensored/177.33.83.129

Request Start time 19.1.2012 7:45:27
Request End time 19.1.2012 7:45:27
Response Start time 19.1.2012 7:45:28
Response End time 19.1.2012 7:45:33
Duration 5.77 sec
Request Duration 532 ms
Response Duration 4.99 sec
Latency 250 ms
Speed 0,24 KB/s
Response speed 0,13 KB/s

Request Header Size 366 bytes
Response Header Size 400 bytes
Request Size 396 bytes
Response Size 272 bytes
Total size 1,40 KB (1434 bytes)
Request Compression -
Response Compression 49,3% (gzip)
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what you mean by "I use other server"? Are you using a different server running the same server-side code? Or are you hitting a different service on that other server? Knowing this would help to determine if the problem is related to network connectivity/speed or if there's something about the service's code and/or configuration.

Comment: So I mean that I am hitting a different service on different server.

Comment: Check my update again :)

Comment: Updated my response below based on your updates. It sounds like TeliaSonera is doing something different with how it routes the requests to your service, and that difference is for some reason not being handled by your service. Server-side log access would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server host you are trying to reach an address that is reachable over the 3G network? When you are on a WiFi network, you likely have the ability to reach any number of domains via that network. Not all of those networks are necessarily visible when you connect via a 3G network.

If that server is available over the 3G network, another possibility is that the service you are hitting could have restrictions, either intentional or accidental, that are being tripped when you come into the service in a different way. An example of an intentional restriction could be a service that looks at the IP address of the requester and only responds if the request is coming from an in-network client. An example of an accidental restriction could be a service that expects a certain header that is automatically inserted by a local network proxy but that never gets inserted when circumventing that proxy by going through 3G.

Do you have any access to servers-side logs that might provide you more guidance? Any control of how the service is configured? It sounds like the 3G service from TeliaSonera is doing something different in its connection that is making a difference in how the message is received (or if it is received at all) by your service.

Comment: Yes, I can reach the address using Safari over 3G too.

Comment: Yes, my colleague have done the server side code with me and I am sure that there is no any restrictions on this code.

I have access to server-side logs. The connections which don't successfully work, will still show in www-access log. Which kind of logs I should check?

Comment: If the server logs show that the connections are getting through, then you need some server-side debugging to see if it's failing to respond for some reason. Exactly what you are looking for depends on the kind of service, what kind of SOAP server you are running, etc.

Comment: Yes, the logs shows that the POST request will get to the server even when doesn't work correctly. 
I am sure about the firewalls, but I dont't know why they would block connections from other carrier.

Comment: So the POST is getting to the service. Dig deeper on the server side to find out (a) if the service is successfully processing the POST request and (b) if the service is successfully sending its response. If it is successfully responding, you might need to do some trickery to be able to log things better on your phones. One approach is to use something like "Charles Proxy" on a local Mac that is tethered via the network that is failing. Then set up an iPhone to use your local Mac as its proxy, and look at the detailed network traffic via Charles' logs to see what it is receiving back.

Comment: I tested Charles Proxy, see the Update 3.

Comment: Problem solved! The Charles proxy showed that the response took too long time (over 5s and the timeout is 5s) so the app for some reason don't wanted to accept the response. My colleague found an gzip bug from the server-side code so the processing is now five times faster.

It is very interesting that the connection took so little more time with other carrier that it didn't work anymore. But now it works! Thanks for Tim Dean!

Comment: Glad to hear! Charles has saved me on more than one occasion. It's a great tool to have in your toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

"The request timed out." - it means it's loading so huge amounts of data that the Edge or 3G connection causes a timeout, as they're not fast enough. Wifi is faster, so it's able to load the whole data before the server cancels the request due to timeout. I suggest you to either try using/transferring less data, or load it in chunks, or asynchronously (if your NSURLConnection doesn't already do this).

Comment: No I think this is not the answer. The network is actually sometimes faster over 3G than over our wifi. I can also tether other iPhone's network over Wifi and connect to that network with iPhone with my app and it still will work. But if I use the same iPhone's 3g, it doesn't work. The amount of the data which I am using is very small.

Answer (score 1):

My iphone would not load facebook up on wifi(all other apps worked fine but facebook stopped loading in safari wed browser And my moms lap top modzilla but other sites worked but worked on my 3g connection. AFTER HOURS of seraching and almost destroying my router (literally) i found a solution: i changed the server used by my router manually by adding the DNS from google and everything started working :)...for now :/ credit to this guy for the suggestion >
http://tidbits.com/article/13259 i got the google dns from him too. try it might work for you as well. maybe we all are having trouble because of the servers on the routers.